# Python double split comprehensions

Tags: python

I want to extract string before @ using python list comprehensions

```
Input: 
["aks@gmail.com", "pks@gmail.com"]

Output:
["aks", "pks"]
```

Here is what i have Tried

```
input_name = [item for mails in list_of_email_address for item in mails.split("@")]
```

Actual Output:

```
[aks, gmail.com, pks, gmail.com]
```

Expected Output

```
[aks, pks]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `str.split()` function returns a `List[str]`. By splitting on `"@"` you're splitting each email address into two parts, the user name and the domain name, e.g. `myname@gmc.com -> ["myname", "gmc.com"]`. What you need is

```py
[email.split("@")[0] for email in list_of_email_address]
```